# Is mongodb migration between clusters using replication a viable option?

Tags: database, mongodb, migration, database-migration

We have a managed mongodb 3.0.11 cluster running on Compose with ~ 300gb of data (call this C0). We want to move this data to a self-managed mongodb 4.x cluster running on GCP (call this C1). I've experimented with a few github repos that were made to clone / sync DBs, but none of them have worked reliably for my tests (and honestly I am not sure I want to use these not-heavily-tested repos to migrate our production data).

While reading through mongodb documentation about replica sets, oplog, etc., it occurred to me that maybe we can get mongodb to do the migration for us via its built-in relica set member addition process. However, since I'm not a mongodb expert, I do not know if this is a viable solution or not.

Here is what I'm interested in - mongodb experts please comment on if this would work (and if you have any experience-based advice on doing it):

- Add two mongodb instances from C1 as priority 0 replica set members to C0
- Wait for C1.members to be up-to-date
- Go into "maintenance mode" - database access clients shut down
- Force-upgrade one of C1.members to be primary
- Remove all C0.members from the replica set
- Restart database clients with new connection string to C1 replica set

Alternative is to write my own cloner / sync since none of the tools I've found so far seem to be production-ready for mongo 4.x.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly not recommend combining cluster migration with upgrading through several major releases. Approaching these tasks separately will help you limit the scope of changes when troubleshooting.

Migrating between clusters using the general approach you outlined is a possibility if you are using compatible MongoDB server versions and able to add all members to the same replica set. Currently only adjacent major server releases are supported for rolling upgrades, so if your starting point is MongoDB 3.0.x the newest version you could directly add to your 3.0.x replica set would be 3.2.x. If your final goal is 4.0.x, you then have to upgrade from 3.2 => 3.4, 3.4 => 3.6, and finally 3.6 => 4.0. The [MongoDB Release Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/) contain specific prerequisites, upgrade procedures, and compatibility information for every major release.

DBaaS providers generally will not allow adding external self-managed members because this could compromise the security and stability of the cluster they manage. However, DBaaS providers often have automation to help you upgrade in place so you may want to take advantage of this before migrating to self-managed.

Your best option for live migration from DBaaS would be to create a user with access to the replication oplog and find a migration tool that suits your use case and source/target server versions. For a production environment I would be wary of trying to live migrate across multiple major releases (eg. 3.0.x to 4.0.x) and would encourage a same version migration (3.0.x => 3.0.x) with separate upgrade steps.

As a general approach I would:

- Review all of the release, upgrade, and compatibility notes for the server and driver upgrades you are planning.
- Ensure you are using compatible driver versions and upgrade your drivers/application code before upgrading server versions.
- Test the upgrade process with a backup of your production data in a representative staging/QA environment.
- Test your application(s) with upgraded driver/server versions and a representative workload to look for potential issues such as performance regressions.

Comment: Thanks @stennie, I agree in general with your proposal. I ended up writing a tool the does a full clone of all records and then live-tails the oplog to get the target in sync. This allowed us to live migrate a 320g database from a 3.0.11 DBaaS provider to a 4.2 DBaaS provider without issues - total migration time was about 12hrs. I'll be releasing the tool as open-source soon.

Comment: @ChrisEdgington Excellent -- please drop a comment here with a link after you open source :). There have been a few such tools but generally they have been created for one-off migrations and unfortunately not actively maintained.